# Arabic Content Not Retrieved from Broker correctly in Web 8

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-1.5

I am trying to retrieve Arabic Content for my website. I am able to save the content in CMS and also able to publish it to Broker correctly. When I am trying to access it from my .NET DXA Application, some characters are getting replaced by '`?`'

I have done the below mappings:
In Master Layout File:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

In Application `Web.Config`:

```
<globalization resourceProviderFactoryType="Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.ResourceProviderFactory, Sdl.Web.Mvc" fileEncoding="UTF-8" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

In Deployer and Discovery Services `cd_storage_conf.xml` file:

```
<Role Name="DeployerCapability" Url="http://localhost:8084/httpupload">
     <Property Name="undo.enabled" Value="false"/>
     <Property Name="encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
</Role>
```

I restarted the Deployer Service, Registered the Discovery Service, and restarted it again.

I am not sure if I am missing anything. Currently, I am using SDL Web 8.1 & DXA 1.5

To add further, please find the original Arabic Text, and the Response Arabic Text.

Original Arabic Text:

```
مبادرة بيرل تكرم (سابك) لقيادتها ومساهمتها البارزة في تعزيز ممارسات الحوكمة والاستدامة في منطقة الخليج
```

Response Arabic Text:

```
مبادرة بيرل تكرم (سابك) لقيادتها ومساهمتها البارزة �?ي تعزيز ممارسات الحوكمة والاستدامة �?ي منطقة الخليج
```

This issue is coming for the Components Published with Dynamic Component Templates. For Component Presentations Embedded on the Page, the Arabic text is coming absolutely fine now.

Please help.

Comment: Can you edit your question and supply a bit more detail which settings you changed exactly, and also which version of Web 8 you are exactly using?

Comment: @Bart: Edited the question with all the details.

Comment: This is quite odd, I've had no problems with this except when the deployer was misconfigured, which is not the case for you

Comment: @Nuno: I checked in DB. The Characters are getting stored correctly. The issue is not, when the .NET DXA Application retrieves the characters. Most of them are coming correctly, only very few are coming as '?'

Comment: @SharadSangal can you edit your question and post a schreenshot, since you mentioning most characters are okay and only a few are not makes this even more strange, everything looks correctly configured?

Comment: @Bart: I have added the Original Arabic Text, and the Arabic Text I got from Response. Hope this helps.

Comment: Really odd. We may want to look at this with some sort of Unicode editor to figure out what character is actually in there.

Comment: The issue is now resolved for the Component Presentations Embedded on the page, but for Dynamic Component Presentations it is still occurring.

Comment: @SharadSangal that is partially good news already, maybe good to answer your own question with the solution up till now, and edit it once it is completely solved. Will be valuable information for everybody who runs into the same issue.

Comment: @Bart: I am trying various options, but now kind of stuck in Dynamic Component Presentations. Will Keep looking into it, and also looking forward for any help from Community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try adding the following `file.encoding` Java System Property to the installation script. For example, for `installService.ps1`:

```
$jvmoptions = "-Xrs", "-Xms256m", "-Xmx256m", "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

There's currently an issue in that the Deployer ignores the encoding property set within the Role configuration.

You will also need to reinstall the service on Windows platforms after making this change.

Comment: Thanks Bengineer!!!!
It resolved the issue for Dynamic Presentations as well.